# PHP fails with comparsion of floats and integers

Tags: php, comparison

See [this](http://pastebin.com/H3dEmd9L) PasteBin and tell me where am I wrong. I think it is possible bug or something wrong with my coding that I am not aware of. Anyways I have tested it on my local machine on PHP 5.3.16 & WebHost Server on PHP 5.3.15. I have simulated the real results from the script, everything before that is working perfectly except this part, no errors thrown.

Live test [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef3d0eb5b7bf34d22100bc6c4a87d26f7437a3af). same results as on the dev and server machines.

Thank you all!

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230305/php-integer-and-float-comparison-mismatch

Comment: 10, 15 or 20.. but the answer that @ulkas gave me is correct I forgot to rename the variable in the first elseif ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your problem lies at `elseif (($taxed >= 99) && ($total < 199)) {`

it should be `elseif (($taxed >= 99) && ($taxed < 199)) {`

Comment: LMAO that was correct. sorry for the dumb mistake... Thanks anyway!