# In php why is a Float > String or Float > int

Tags: php

In testing with cash conversions I ran into this.  If I set the 510 to intval() it still says that the float * 100 is less than the string or int.  Why does php do that?

```
$var = 4.73 + .37;
$amt = 510;
if($var * 100 > 510){
    echo 'wtf';
}
```

Comment: Welcome to floating point arithmetic.

Comment: place var_dump( $var, $amt ); before the if statement. You'll find your answer there.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/ Read it. And don't use floating point ever anymore for money. Use an int and count cents.

Comment: This question already exist, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230305/php-integer-and-float-comparison-mismatch), and the answer is in the [PHP Manual - Floating point numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) - see red big warning box.

Answer (score 5):

it's all about floating point arithmetic. The same problem occurs in every other programming language

the simplest example:
    0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004

you won't see it if you use `echo` or even `var_dump` because it will be truncated to show in a human friendly form, but you can see it clearly here:

```
$a = 0.3; // true 0.3
$b = 0.1 + 0.2; // approximately 0.3

var_dump($a); // 0.3
var_dump($b); // 0.3

var_dump($a == $b); // false

var_dump($a == 0.3); // true
var_dump($b == 0.3); // false

var_dump($a == 0.30000000000000004); // false
var_dump($b == 0.30000000000000004); // true
```

**Don't use floats to store money amount and especially to do any calculations on them** - use cents or fixed point arithmetic (if applicable)

Comment: +1 don't use floats to store money amount

Comment: @Adassko what should we use for store money amount

Comment: I'll +1 it if he makes it bold and blinking ;-)).

Comment: @SatishSharma ints and count cents.

Comment: This is a way better answer than the other thread.  Also when googling and typing in the question into stack the other didn't come up.  Thank you for giving another actual example.