# How to check if a number (float or integer) is within a range (0 - 100)

Tags: php, regex, range

I'm looking for the fastest way to get this test. 
So `functions`, `operands` and everything else is allowed.
I tried with the following `regex` (I'm not an expert):

```
0\.[0-9]+|100\.0+|100|[1-9]\d{0,1}\.{0,1}[0-9]+
```

It works except that it erroneously accept `0.0` or `0.000000` and so on.
Also **it's not the most appropriated and fastest way**.

(if anybody wants to fix the regex to don't allow those `0.00` values it would be appreciated)`

Comment: Why don't you convert the string to a number and then compare numbers? Wouldn't that be much easier?

Comment: I'm not sure that regex is the best way to go about doing this.

Comment: yes I'm not looking necessarily for a regex, if you have others solution are well accepted, I just edited the question

Comment: Regex is obviously not a tool for that. change `0\.[0-9]+` with `0\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks. I know a regex it's not the best. That's why I asked the fastest way to do it. I tried your regex but it doesn't accept `0.001`. Am I right?

Comment: Refresh you browser, the comment has changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for regex:

```
if (is_numeric($val) && $val > 0 && $val <= 100)
{
    echo '$val is number (int or float) between 0 and 100';
}
```

## [Demo](https://eval.in/243280)

*Update*

It turns out you're getting the numeric values from a string. In that case, it would be best to extract all of them using a regex, something like:

```
if (preg_match_all('/\d+\.?\d*/', $string, $allNumbers))
{
    $valid = [];
    foreach ($allNumbers[0] as $num)
    {
        if ($num > 0 && $num <= 100)
            $valid[] = $num;
    }
}
```

You can leave out the `is_numeric` check, because the matched strings are guaranteed to be numeric anyway...

Comment: `is_numeric(1e0)` returns `true` - so I think regex is the sollution

Comment: Maybe, but anyway for my use case I'll probably need to first do a regex to extract the number (int or float) from a string with something like this `([0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]*)` and then check that the number is in the range with the posted solution.

Comment: @kuus You don't need a regex. Look at my answer.

Comment: @violator667: that's because `1e0` _is_ numeric, it's the same as `1^0` (1 to the power of 0), which is, by definition, and therefore a valid value... try `var_dump(1e0);` in php, it dumps 1

Comment: @Tek my problem is that the number is in a string with other stuff like: `sometext($),@31.321312(rew)` so I need to extact it from there and then do the check.

Comment: @kuus: extract numeric values using a regex like so: `preg_match_all('/\d+\.?\d*/', $string, $allNumbers)`, then process all numbers using my answer, but you can leave out the `is_numeric` check, because `preg_match_all` already guarantees the matches to be numeric

Comment: actually I need a regex a bit more like this `(0\.[0-9]*|[1-9]{0,1}\d+\.{0,1}[0-9]+)` because I can't allow a value `013`, it would return true in the range check but in my use case it's not ok.

Comment: This doesn't work with a calculated float if the value is something like 100.000001493894, or 0.9999985378683

Comment: @Tim nothing you can do about that, really... those numbers cause rounding issues due to the fact that PHP uses the IEEE 754 double precision format. There are extensions specifically built to get around some of the headaches that come with these type of numbers (BC math comes to mind). There probably are some libraries you could use, too

Comment: comparing int and float is bad.

Comment: @Inoyatulloh internally, they're `zval`'s, which will be coerced to comparable types anyway. Sure, coersion happens beyond your control, but then the internal conversion is no different to a cast. At least, that was how it worked back in the day when I was developing PHP extensions, and delved deep down into the bowels of the Zend engine

Answer (score 4):

## Use [bccomp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php)

This is a perfect use case for BCMath functions.

```
function compare_numberic_strings($number) {
    if (
        is_numeric($number) &&
        bccomp($number, '0') === 1 &&
        bccomp($number, '100') === -1
    ) {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}

echo compare_numberic_strings('0.00001');
//returns true

echo compare_numberic_strings('50');
//returns true

echo compare_numeric_strings('100.1');    
//returns false

echo compare_numeric_strings('-0.1');
//returns false
```

From the manual:

> Returns 0 if the two operands are equal, 1 if the left_operand is
> larger than the right_operand, -1 otherwise.

Comment: Is this faster than the above answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27986661/1938970 ?

Comment: @kuus First of all, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470990/is-micro-optimization-worth-the-time . But to answer your question, yes. These functions are written internally in C. Which is much faster than PHP itself. PLUS. And this is a big PLUS. You should never use `<`, `>` to compare floats. *Ever.* There's a big fat warning on the PHP.net as well about this http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float.comparison . That's what the BCMath functions are for.

Comment: @Tek: bollocks... these functions are written in C -> yes, so? C is much faster than PHP -> yes. What language is PHP written in? => **C**. No matter how you look at it `$val > 0 && $val <= 100` is comparing 2 `zval` (the internal representation of a PHP variable). `bccomp` is _calling a function_, which is more expensive than comparing 2 scalar values, Always.

Comment: @Tek Thanks, I know all the talking, thinking and problems about micro-optimization, but I still wanted to know what was the fastest :)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Either way comparing floats using traditional operators is a big no no.

Comment: @kuus You're welcome. Sure beats having to use expensive regexes ;)

Comment: @Tek: Why would comparing 2 `double`'s be so terribly unreliable in this particular case? So much so, even, that you'd rather parse a stringified number into a struct, to compare that struct using a [ton of helper functions and heap memory](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/bcmath/bcmath.c#L513). Check the implementation of `bccomp` before claiming anything regarding its performance. It clearly wasn't designed to be _fast_, it was designed to counter possible rounding issues with the IEEE754 spec, but OP isn't doing any arithmetic here

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Because we don't know what his data set looks like and maybe neither does he. Everything in there is for a good reason, they're not wasted calculations. It's safer to use functions written specially for this purpose so we can avoid questions like these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230305/php-integer-and-float-comparison-mismatch

Comment: @Tek: The question you linked to, like any other question concerning issues with floating point numbers, performs computations. OP specified in a comment to my answer, that the numbers he's after are extracted from a string. No computation, no rounding issues. I'm just advocating to keep things simple

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Even then you need to specify what you need the smallest acceptable difference  when comparing such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php

It's just better to use BCMath functions and not have to worry about floating point numbers at all.

Plus you can guarantee any kind of computation with them. You don't want to accidentally compute on a floating point because you're used to using normal operators and comparing them afterwards. It's better to become acquainted with proper programming techniques in PHP

Comment: @Tek: Again: linked question deals with computation of floating-point numbers. Besides, a very common (much more common than using bmath), easier alternative in both PHP _and_ C is to not use decimals (just use `long` or `int`, and divide by 100 for output). Yes, floating-point arithmetic is error-prone, but honestly, KISS. I know you'll probably link to yet another question, or tell me to put in `.1 + .2` in a JS console, but frankly, this is a pointless discussion, and is very much off topic here. Let's either agree that PHP is not the best tool for arithmetic, or agree to disagree

Comment: I agree, although there's still much to learn. lol @ the js console part

Answer (score 0):

I think your `regex` pattern should look like this:

```
^\d{1,2}$|(100)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tQ3lE2/1)

Comment: This regex is wrong for this use case, I'd vote down the answer but I can't.