# PHP Comparing two values of type integer and double is giving incorrect results

Tags: php, comparison, gettype

I am checking the value of the amount paid as sent by **stripe webhook** versus the **invoice amount due** that is in my database.

In my database, the invoice amount is stored as **decimal(10,2)**

I have 10 invoices of 33.60 each = 336.00

```
//i.e.
$invoices_amount = 336.00;
```

Stripe is correctly sending the amount as 336

```
{
"gateway_transaction_id":"ch_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"internal_transaction_id":"22",
"transaction_amount":336,
"transaction_currency":"usd",
"transaction_status":"passed"
}
```

```
//i.e.
$transaction_amount = 336;
```

however when I do my validation logic to check if the amount paid is equal to the invoices total, the comparison is return false

```
    if($transaction_amount >= $invoices_amount){
        //passed
    }else{
      //failed
    }
```

I am getting failed in the above check.

I have checked the variable types using gettype:

```
gettype($transaction_amount) = integer

gettype($invoices_amount) = double
```

What is even more odd, is that this used to validate just fine all along.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230305/php-integer-and-float-comparison-mismatch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php integer and float comparison mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230305/php-integer-and-float-comparison-mismatch)

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code, It is working fine with me. eg,

```
<?php

$invoices_amount    = 360.00;
$stripe_amount      = 360;

 if($stripe_amount >= $invoices_amount)
  {
        //passed
        echo 'passed'; 
  }
else
  {
      //failed
      echo 'failed';  
  }
?>
```

Is giving me 'passed' result. May be you can try to convert the stripe amount to float like this:

```
<?php
$invoices_amount    = 360.00;
$stripe_amount      = (float)360;
if($stripe_amount >= $invoices_amount)
{
//passed
echo 'passed'; 
}
else
{
//failed
echo 'failed';  
}
?>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BC-MATH extension when comparing two numbers.

```
$result = bccomp($transaction_amount, $invoices_amount, 2);
```

`$result` will be 0 when `$transaction_amount = $invoices_amount`

`$result` will be 1 when `$transaction_amount > $invoices_amount`

`$result` will be -1 when `$transaction_amount < $invoices_amount`

### or

cast `$transaction_amount` to float
`(float)$transaction_amount`, then compare.